# How to plot a constantly updating candlestick chart within python

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code that gets trade data from a websocket then calculates some candlestick data and adds it into a pandas dataframe. I would like to plot a candlestick chart using this dataframe that updates everytime a new candle is added into the dataframe. I have looked at matplotlib and plotly but can't seem to get the charts to update.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.